# Cannot find element using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, drop-down-menu

I am not able to find the element "Inventory" using xpath. I am not sure if I am using it correctly. I currently do not have access to add alt tags.

```
// C#
IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']"));
IWebElement inventory = dropdown.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='Inventory']           /@href"));

//html
<li class="dropdown open">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Inventory
           <i class="caret"></i>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
              <a href="/government/product-categories">Product Categories</a>
          </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some whitespace around the term "Inventory". User `contains(...)` to perform a substring search:

```
//a[contains(., 'Inventory')]
```